# href links with multiple ## are not successfully escaped using backslah escape

Tags: href

Using LaTeX I'm trying to create a hyperlink using href, where the url contains multiple # symbols. I am fully aware special characters have to be escaped, e.g. with % this is even rather typical in links. However today I came upon a link containing two #, where I somehow am only able to escape the first, escaping the second one does not work (and all solutions I tried broke the document one way or another). Is this something obvious I'm missing (even though a befriended LaTeX user would also not get it to run) or is it some black magic I'm unaware of? The problem is the following, an example is shared below via overleaf:

```
\href{http://www.example.com/hey\#foo}{This link is not broken (should be http://www.example.com/hey\#foo)}
The above works, only one hashtag has to be escaped
\href{http://www.example.com/hey\#foo\#bar}{This link is broken (should be http://www.example.com/hey\#foo\#bar but is http://www.example.com/hey\#foo)}
This does not work, as two hashes would have to be escaped
```

Example on overleaf: [Overleaf link, also in comment](https://www.overleaf.com/read/gtxwymyrcrzk)

Comment: Please move your example here. External links tend to rot over time and thus your question will not be useful for others.

Comment: hm can a valid url contain two hashes? Do you have an reference?

Comment: BTW: a good example would be to compare it to `\url{http://www.example.com/hey#foo#bar}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think so, but compare it to `\url{http://www.example.com/hey#foo#bar}` which does generate a URL with two `#`'s

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have, but I can not share it, as it an invite link to the messaging system at my university :D If it makes a difference though: The actual structure encountered looks something like http://www.example.com/hey/#/#bar (slash hash  slash hash otherstuff)

Comment: \url indeed works for it and is currently my workaround - but I would of course prefer a solution that shows custom anchor text rather than the link

Comment: @daleif asked to move the example link here (if I understand correctly) - here you go: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gtxwymyrcrzk

Comment: No, copy the code into your question. As I mentioned, links rot and thus in the future people cannot access your example unless the actual code is listed here.

Comment: @daleif can't do as StackExchange complains this would have too many characters, sorry! I hope the code provided above is enough for reproduction of the problem

Comment: That example you link to is miniscule and can easily be added here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well hyperref doesn't expect that and the splitting code throws away everything after the second hash. You can use a hash with catcode letter instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N\hashletter
\tl_set:Nx\hashletter{\char_generate:nn{35}{11}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\href{http://www.example.com/hey#foo\hashletter bar}{blub}

\end{document}
```

With the new pdfmanagement you can use `\hrefurl` instead. It doesn't try to be clever and split the url:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase} %needed until next latex
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hrefurl{http://www.example.com/hey#foo#bar}{blub}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The upper solution works, the lower one seems to break on overleaf (I assume this might be something with overleaf rather than in itself not working?). I will mark this as the answer, as soon as I can reproduce the second one outside of overleaf / someone confirms it is working outside of overleaf!

Comment: the second needs a quite new latex, the overleaf system is too old (it could work there with \DeclareDocumentMetadata{} instead of \DocumentMetadata{})

Comment: Just for the record: Multiple hash signs in URLs are not supported by the relevant standard (= RFC 3986): Everything after the first # is considered a “fragment“, and in addition to letters and numbers only some other 7bit ASCII characters are allowed. Most notably absent is the pound / hash sign. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088849/url-fragment-allowed-characters for more details.